# Wrap an Image (or Video!?) around a Cylinder - Webkit CSS 3d Transform

Tags: image, video, webkit, css-transforms

Goal:
Wrap a panoramic Image/Video around a Cylinder and control a "camera" on the inside to look around a pano.

First thing's first, I cannot find any example of an image, let alone a video, wrapped around a cylinder. Anyone know how to do this?

I think I should be fine with the interactive aspects of controlling the viewport with the mouse or arrow keys, but I have no clue how to begin with this cylinder stuff, as I'm kinda a noob with CSS transformations and 3d webkit coding…

Love you long time - thank you so much for any answers!
-Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this exact same thing today.  I came across this question this morning, so wanted to post a bit of help.

Generated code:

```
<div class="view-Cylinder-Background" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; -webkit-perspective-origin-x: 50%; -webkit-perspective-origin-y: 50%; -webkit-perspective: 500; ">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; -webkit-transform: translateZ(1222.3099629457563px); ">
        <div style="-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: auto; width: 0px; -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform; -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; -webkit-transform: rotateY(-748.5000000000005deg); ">
            <div class="view-Cylinder-Item" style="position: absolute; left: -77px; -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(1195.5154099609108px) translateY(0px); -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform; -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; ">
                <div style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); ">
                    <div style="background-image: url(images/panarama.jpg); width: 153px; height: 1024px; background-position: 0px 0px; ">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="view-Cylinder-Item" style="position: absolute; left: -77px; -webkit-transform: rotateY(7.2deg) translateZ(1195.5154099609108px) translateY(0px); -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform; -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; ">
                <div style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); ">
                    <div style="background-image: url(images/panarama.jpg); width: 153px; height: 1024px; background-position: 153.6px 0px; ">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="view-Cylinder-Item" style="position: absolute; left: -77px; -webkit-transform: rotateY(14.4deg) translateZ(1195.5154099609108px) translateY(0px); -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform; -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; ">
                <div style="-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); ">
                    <div style="background-image: url(images/panarama.jpg); width: 153px; height: 1024px; background-position: 307.2px 0px; ">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the outer divs are the cylinder itself.  The 3 "view-Cylinder-Item" divs are faces on that cylinder.  This particular example is split into 50 faces (cut for brevity sake), so each face is rotated by `7.2 degrees`.  The `translateZ` of the faces is calculated by basic geometry (pythagoras: `sqrt( radius^2 - face_width^2 )`.  Radius is calculated as `imageWidth / Pi / 2` and is used in the `translateZ` of the wrapping div (`1222... pixels`).  Each face is also offset by `-50%` (`left: -77px`) to place it in the correct location.

Hope this helps a bit, I know this is question is a few months old.

Comment: HOLY CHIT! I cannot wait to see how this works out! Thank you so much Cwolves!!

Comment: heh, haven't logged in in a while?  :)

Comment: haha, yeah i guess it's been awhile - hey, i just got around to trying this code and the images aren't showing up. I put a panorama.jpg file in a folder images, and while it's loading the image, and I can view the wireframes of the elements, I cannot see the image itself. I also see classes that I don't have… do you by chance have a live version of this or a complete document? Maybe it's just a stab in the dark, but maybe the three panels you coded are facing the wrong direction? i donno… thanks again bud!

Comment: @Mala -- probably :)  But I haven't touched this in years.