# Java Image manipulation curve-bend image

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I have two images
the first image of a cup ->
[image: Paper cup]

the second image is the label I want to wrap around the cup (this image is just an example, the actual app works with dynamic images).

[image: Cup lable]

I'm planning to clip the label image several time and place it on the cup, therefor creating a 36 jpegs from different angles, I'll use a 360 viewer to display the result on my website.

so far I've managed to take a trapezoid area of the lable image to create this
(code is [here](https://codepad.co/snippet/eIIewDWL))

[image]

The last step is to create this (used GIMP for this - using distort -> curve-bending)
[image]

Thank you

Comment: If you are willing to use bash shell script with Imagemagick, see http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cylinderize/index.php. But it will be similar timing to running Imagemagick.

Comment: These might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997344/wrap-an-image-around-a-cylindrical-object-in-html5-javascript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636730/wrap-an-image-or-video-around-a-cylinder-webkit-css-3d-transform

Comment: Already solved. My Java solution is super fast for me. 3.45 sec to generate 36 images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do some work.
At first, I use ImageMagick , it took 50 sec to generate 36 images... way to long for me.
So I turned to Java, I've managed to do the simple transformation using a simple pixel by pixel and apply a Sin function

```
for(int y = 0; y < bounds.height ; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < bounds.width ; x++) {
                        int pixelRGB = img.getRGB(x, y);
                        int newX = x;
                        int newY = ((int)(Math.sin(x*Math.PI/bounds.width) * 40 )) + y  ;
                        newImg.setRGB(newX, newY, pixelRGB);            
                    }
                }
```

### main line is -> (Math.sin(x * Math.PI / bounds.width) * 40) + y

- Math.PI / bounds.width -> make sure I get only the positive values for Y from the Sin function.
- bounds.width - is the original image width, for the Sin function it tells to start from 0,0 go to positive Y values and intersec with th X axis back at bounds.width.
- 40 -> is the level of curvature you'll want to use
- y - just a Y axis offset. if not applied you'll  get a single line in the target image

Answer (score 0):

What comes in my mind, is a technique called uv-mapping. 
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping as a starting point.

See also [J3D - How to use a UV mapping of an object to convert 2D coordinates to 3D ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688900/j3d-how-to-use-a-uv-mapping-of-an-object-to-convert-2d-coordinates-to-3d-ones)

Comment: you are suggesting texture mapping, I don't want to do any rendering or use textures. thank you any way